# How to do floating point arithmetic in substrate runtime

Tags: blockchain, substrate, parity-io

How can I do math on floating point values in substrate runtime. As a simple example imagine I want to keep track of an interest rate in a decentralized finance.

I can prototype by using the percentage as an integer

```rust
let rate = 2;
let dividend = capital * rate / 100;
```

But what if my interest rate is 2.5% or 2.4554%?

Is there any standard way to do floating point arithmetic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Substrate is a framework for blockchains, it is important that each node arrives at the same *deterministic* result for consensus.

Floating point arithmetic is **not** deterministic and so for this reason is not allowed in Substrate.

The standard way of handling arithmetic where you will need decimal places is to use one of the in-built primitive types for handling *fixed point* arithmetic. Fixed point arithmetic is safe for Substrate since it represents all rationals as a fraction and always resolves to a deterministic result.

The two types which are used to handle fixed point arithmetic are the [Permill](https://crates.parity.io/sr_primitives/struct.Permill.html) and the [Perbill](https://crates.parity.io/sr_primitives/struct.Perbill.html) types.